# Play 2.1 Scala chain multiple futures and promises

Tags: scala, future, playframework-2.1, promise

I have an existing java class for processing data. How could I use the ObjectNode from first promise and so more processing in my Scala Async action?

```
public class JavaClass extends Controller {
  public static Promise<ObjectNode> intensiveComputation(String imageId) {
  }
}


def index = Action {
  val futureInt = scala.concurrent.Future { JavaClass.intensiveComputation() }
  Async {
    futureInt.map(promise => 
      var objJs = promise.GetObjectNodeFromPromise()
      (objJs \ Config.RESP_STATUS_PARAM).as[String] match {
        // I WANT TO READ ObjectNode from promise and do more works here
      }
      Ok(Json.toJson(Map("status" -> "ok")))
  }
}
```

> EDIT 1

I tried with @hbf code, however, I got compiling error one this line.

```
[error]  found   : org.codehaus.jackson.node.ObjectNode => play.api.mvc.SimpleResult[play.api.libs.json.JsValue]
[error]  required: play.libs.F.Function[org.codehaus.jackson.node.ObjectNode,?]
[error]                 var result = futureObj map { objJs: ObjectNode =>
```

If I remove ObjectNode from objJs, I got this error.

```
[error]  missing parameter type
[error]                 var result = futureObj map { objJs =>
```

New Code

```
def index = Action {
  val futureInt = JavaClass.intensiveComputation()
  Async {
    var result = futureObj map { objJs: ObjectNode =>
      Ok(Json.toJson(Map("status" -> "ok")))
    }
    result
}
```

Answer (score 4):

I assume you are following the [Play documentation guide](http://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.1.0/ScalaAsync), right?

First of all, notice that Play is now (from version 2.1 on) using Scala futures and due to this, the nomenclature changed: your method `intensiveComputation()` returns a (Scala) `Future<ObjectNode>` (while in pre-2.1, this was called `Promise<ObjectNode>`).

```java
public class JavaClass extends Controller {
  public static Future<ObjectNode> intensiveComputation(String imageId) {
    /* ... */
  }
}
```

Also, note that in the [Play documentation example](http://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.1.0/ScalaAsync), `intensiveComputation()` returns the value (i.e., `ObjectNode`) directly, while your version returns a future holding the value (i.e., `Future<ObjectNode>`).

Second, in your `futureInt.map`, the closure receives the value of the future and not the future itself. So try something like:

```scala
def index = Action {
  val futureInt = JavaClass.intensiveComputation() // I's already a future!
  Async {
    futureInt.map(objJs => // `objJs` is the result of `intensiveComputation`
      // Extract from `objJs` whatever you need ...
      // ... and make the `Ok` call here (and not outside)
      Ok(Json.toJson(Map("status" -> "ok")))
    )
  }
}
```

Comment: I tried futureInt.map(objJs =>. However, I got this error. [error]  found   : org.codehaus.jackson.node.ObjectNode => play.api.mvc.SimpleResult[play.api.libs.json.JsValue]
[error]  required: play.libs.F.Function[org.codehaus.jackson.node.ObjectNode,?]

Comment: It's also worth mentioning that simply by Googling "Scala Async" you get as your first hit the docs for Play 2.0. Seems Play changed the concept of async programming dramatically in 2.1 (from Promise[T] to Future[T]) so those docs are outdated.